# R: expand.grid() function is not being executed and throwing error

Tags: r

I am working on census income data and creating a logistic regression model.
I've been trying to visualise the training set results after predicting the test data.
I have installed `ElemStatLearn` package and have set x1 and x1.
following is the code:

```
x1 <- seq(min(set[,6]) - 1, max(set[,6]) + 1, by = 0.01)
x2 <- seq(min(set[,7]) - 1, max(set[,7]) + 1, by = 0.01)
grid_set <- expand.grid(x1,x2)
```

However, after executing the expand.grid function I am encountering the following error:

> "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 16235.0 Gb"

Can you help me out with the code or if there are any alterative for the expand.grid() function.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to make quite a big vector. I'am not sure if an alternative function would help. We don't know what is in `set`. Can you show us what is in `set`. You can use `dput(set)` or if it is really big `dput(head(set, 20))` or show what is in `x1` and `x2`.

Comment: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Adult
This is the URL for the dataset.

Comment: If you are not going to use all points `(x1,x2)` in the space `grid_set`, I suggest you focus on the points that are useful for your purpose... otherwise I suspect there is no alternative for `grid_set` for the whole space of points...

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Thank you for your help. It gave me an idea about the correct approach.